# Count and aggregate by date

Tags: r, date, count, aggregate

The dataset:

```
Date
2021-09-25T17:07:24.222Z    
2021-09-25T16:17:20.376Z
2021-09-24T09:30:53.013Z
2021-09-24T09:06:24.565Z
```

I would like to count the number of rows per day. For example, 2021-09-25 will be 2.

To solve said challenge I looked at the following post:

- [Count and Aggregate Date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139720/count-and-aggregate-date-in-r)

The answer of Rorshach is the solution. However, I do not understand how I can format my rows in the Date column to 2021/09/24 instead of 2021-09-24T09:06:24.565Z.

Could someone explain to me how to format the entries in the Date column?

Comment: Have you tried `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)` ? `as.Date('2021-09-25T17:07:24.222Z')` works correctly.

Comment: @RonakShah I have and it works. However, I am unable to cut per day as shown by Rorschach. How does this happen?

Comment: I understand it! Thank you for your tip Ronak Shah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the string into a datetime object and then extract the date (without the hours and minutes) to be able to count:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

tibble::tribble(
  ~Date,
  "2021-09-25T17:07:24.222Z",
  "2021-09-25T16:17:20.376Z",
  "2021-09-24T09:30:53.013Z",
  "2021-09-24T09:06:24.565Z"
) %>%
  mutate(
    day = Date %>% parse_datetime() %>% as.Date()
  ) %>%
  count(day)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   day            n
#>   <date>     <int>
#> 1 2021-09-24     2
#> 2 2021-09-25     2
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I do not understand the solution. What is the purpose of 'day = Date'?

Comment: Your example mentioned the colum `Date` which is actually a datetime. The `day` column is added to the table representing only the date. This is different from the datetime thus I created another column to prevent confusion. The column `day` starts with `Date`, then the two functions were applied.

Answer (score 2):

After converting the date you may use `table` to count occurrence of each Date.

```
table(as.Date(df$Date))

#2021-09-24 2021-09-25 
#         2          2
```

Answer (score 1):

@RonakShah's answer is good, but to have the dataframe in better format, use the `count` function from the `plyr` library:

```
library(plyr)
count(as.Date(df$Date))
```

Output:

```
           x freq
1 2021-09-24    2
2 2021-09-25    2
```